# Weird post pagination url redirect

Tags: themes

I have this example link: `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
If I put 1 page break on the post content, redirects are as follows:

`/uncategorized/hello-world/1` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
redirect and is my ideal behavior.

`/uncategorized/hello-world/2` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/2`
no redirect, it's expected.

`/uncategorized/hello-world/3` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
redirect and is my ideal behavior.

**BUT** if I remove the page break on the post content, only `/uncategorized/hello-world/1` works.
If page is 1, it removes the 1 in the url, but other than that it accepts the number.

`/uncategorized/hello-world/1` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
`/uncategorized/hello-world/2` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/2`
`/uncategorized/hello-world/99` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/99`

Is there any way to make it so any number should redirect as if there was no number at all.

`/uncategorized/hello-world/1` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
`/uncategorized/hello-world/2` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
`/uncategorized/hello-world/99` => `/uncategorized/hello-world/`
But only when there's no page break added on the post.

Comment: So if you have no page break /1 goes to / but /2 goes to /2 ?

Comment: @mozboz yes, whatever number. But if with page break, only those valid page numbers. Invalid page numbers got removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually the default behavior when the post does **not** have any page breaks (i.e. the `<!--nextpage-->` tag).

More specifically, in [`redirect_canonical()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L160), WordPress only performs a redirect if the post has the page break tag — and that the page number is invalid (e.g. requesting for page #3 when there are only 2 pages). Otherwise (i.e. no page breaks), those paginated URLs/requests are seen as valid and WordPress doesn't do any redirects except for the first page (e.g. `/hello-world/1`) because the content is considered a duplicate of `/hello-world`.

So for those "valid" requests, if you want to redirect them to the first page, you can use the [`pre_handle_404` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_handle_404/) like so:

```php
add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', function ( $bool ) {
    if ( is_singular( [ 'post', 'page', 'etc' ] ) && get_query_var( 'page' ) &&
        false === strpos( get_queried_object()->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' )
    ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_queried_object() ) );
        exit;
    }

    return $bool;
} );
```

You can also use the `wp` hook, but the `pre_handle_404` seems better since it's called first:

```php
add_action( 'wp', function ( $wp ) {
    if ( is_singular( [ 'post', 'page', 'etc' ] ) && get_query_var( 'page' ) &&
        false === strpos( get_queried_object()->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' )
    ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_queried_object() ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

And I'm using `is_singular()` to target singular requests like single Post (post type `post`) pages.

Comment: Thanks. These make sense..